# LINQ filtering items within the list between two specified dates

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datetime, filter

I have a List of type like following:

```
class GroupedItem
{
  public DateTime _Date {get;set;}
  pubilc int sales {get;set;}
}
```

Where the list is defined as:

```
List<GroupedItem> _groupedItems = new List<GroupedItem>();
```

I'd like to remove all items from list starting from DateTime.Now and into past 7,14, 21 or 30 days from the list by somehow specifying this using LINQ...

How could I do this ?

Edit: the method I've tried is like following:

```
  var selectedDates = Enumerable
    .Range(0, int.MaxValue)
    .Select(index => new DateTime?(StartDate.AddDays(index)))
    .TakeWhile(date => date <= EndDate)
    .ToList();
```

But this returns me empty list...

Edit: Guys, how could I do the following:

```
   var date_range = Int32.Parse(Session["drange"].ToString());
                ViewBag.LineGraph = _groupedItems
                      .GroupBy(l => l._Date.Date)
                      .Select(cl => new GroupedItem
                      {
                           _Date = cl.Key,
                           Sales = cl.Sum(c=>c.Sales)
                      })
                      .OrderBy(x => x._Date)
                      .Where(t => t._Date <= DateTime.Now &&
                      t._Date >= DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(date_range)))
                      .ToList();
```

Is there a way to upgrade this and to remove only dates which are not in the time range given by the parameters (which is Today's date - DateTime.Now and - 7 days into the past...

For example if I have date 14th of December, that one would be removed, but the one from 18th isn't since it' belongs to those 7 days range... ?

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @RajshekarReddy Yes one moment I'll update my question

Comment: Well how about applying a `where` condition on a `_Date` prop? By the way you absolutely have to make it public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var filtered = _groupedItems
                 .Where(t=>t._Date<=DateTime.Now && 
                           t._Date>=DateTime.Now.Substract(TimeSpan.FromDays(7)));
```

You could just replace 7 in the query with other values: *14/21/30*

It makes new filtered collection from an old one, i think it what you want, not to remove items from an exisiting list.

Comment: current date to past 7 days.. not future

Comment: @RajshekarReddy yes, thank  you for correction, is fixed

Comment: @MaksimSimkin One sec I'm testing ur solution

Comment: @MaksimSimkin Is there a way to upgrade this and to remove only dates which are not in the time range given by the parameters (which is Today's date - DateTime.Now and - 7 days into the past...

For example if I have date 14th of December, that one would be removed, but the one from 18th isn't since it' belongs to those 7 days... ?

Comment: You want to negate the check? just do it  : _groupedItems
                 .Where(t=>!(t._Date<=DateTime.Now &&                            t._Date>=DateTime.Now.Substract(TimeSpan.FromDays(7))));

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to compare difference in days you can do this

```
list.RemoveAll(x=>( DateTime.Now.Subtract(x.dt1).Days == 7));
```

Here is a sample

```
Class1 cls1 = new Class1();
cls1.dt1 = DateTime.Parse("22/11/2016");
Class1 cls2 = new Class1();
cls2.dt1 = DateTime.Parse("15/12/2016");
Class1 cls3 = new Class1();
cls3.dt1 = DateTime.Parse("08/11/2016");
Class1 cls4 = new Class1();
cls4.dt1 = DateTime.Parse("22/11/2016");
Class1 cls5 = new Class1();
cls5.dt1 = DateTime.Parse("22/12/2016");

List<Class1> list = new List<Class1>() { cls1, cls2, cls3, cls4, cls5 };

list.RemoveAll(x=>( DateTime.Now.Subtract(x.dt1).Days == 7));

public class Class1
{
  public DateTime dt1 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `RemoveAll()` and using `DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-7)` you can get date  7 days ago.

```
_groupedItems.RemoveAll(d => d._Date >= DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-7));
```

Comment: this would basically remove items from Today's date -7 days into the past no ?

Comment: probably you intended `||` instead of `&&`

Comment: @ArturUdod Just tested this solution, out of 37 items that I had in the list , 37 stayed in the list itself... Some of the dates were back in 10th of October, they werent removed...

Comment: Well the problem might be this code required the dates to be `exactly` equal including milliseconds. I'd better compare the `_Date.Date` part